# Image.network() does not show some image URL's

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple program which shows the image of the image URL:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(itemList[itemIndex].name),
        ),
        body: Image.network(
            "https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"));
  }
```

With these URLs:

https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
and

https://picsum.photos/250?image=9

For example, it works properly. But

https://img.kitapyurdu.com/v1/getImage/fn:11262922/wh:true/wi:0/mh:150

And

https://img.kitapyurdu.com/v1/getImage/fn:11250623/wh:fca476ca7

Images do not show up. Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: what is the file type of your image in second url ?

Comment: If you mean .png or .jpg, I don't know. I am just trying to get images. Does this matter?

Comment: yes  in flutter, it matters if your stored file type is .svg

Comment: I checked your url, it is working, check your internet connection

Comment: https://img.kitapyurdu.com/v1/getImage/fn:11250623/wh:fca476ca7 checked this one

Comment: Internet works fine, I get this error with the URL you tried; Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///img.kitapyurdu.com/v1/getImage/fn:11250623/wh:fca476ca7

Comment: And this one; Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
 CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your internet connectivity. The problem is not reproducable. I have already got those images too. This is the related code:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Image.network(
      "https://img.kitapyurdu.com/v1/getImage/fn:11250623/wh:fca476ca7"),
);
```

And the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had to change my DNS to 8.8.8.8 and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If my answer is helped you, you can accept it :)